# Replace linked shortcuts with actual paths to files and folders in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer, file-management, file-shortcut

I have a folder:

`X:\cases\XYZ` and in this folder I have 2 subfolders and a windows shortcut (.lnk) file that points to another share:

```
Research
Files
3d.lnk ==> Z:\3d\XYZ
```

I have a user that wants to copy "All the Files and Folders" in `X:\cases\XYZ` to an external USB drive `F` but copy and paste doesn't move 3d.lnk subfolders & files.

Does anyone know how I can do this without code and without manually creating the 3d directory?

Comment: Does this help you?   https://superuser.com/questions/508684/modifying-windows-shortcut-lnk-files-target-into-a-relative-path

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an LNK file.  These mostly exist because when they were invented (199x), the file system didn't support symbolic links.  LNK files were *sort of* a workaround to make explorer.exe bada$$ on a Windows machine.

I suggest that you use an NTFS symbolic link(s) INSTEAD of shortcut(s).

`mklink /D "X:\cases\XYZ" "\\bob_the_server\my_xyz_folder"`

It may not work for what you are looking for but it probably will.

Comment: Going to test this today. Thanks.