# How to set Windows Shortcut icon to relative path?

Tags: windows, icons, shortcuts

### Background

I have a Windows Shortcut that executes a file using a relative path.
Now, I want this shortcut to have a nice icon. I already have the icon image and I placed it close to the `bat` file my shortcut is pointing to.

### Problem

The problem here is that I fail to set the path for the shortcut Icon like I set the `target`. Windows seems intent in having me define an absolute path for the icon, which I can't do because it will be different from machine to machine.

So I really want the path to the icon to be relative as well.

I have tried using `%CD%` but this is not recognizable, even though it works just fine in the Shortcut `target`.

### Question

How can I set a shortcut Icon using a relative path (to where the shortcut is) in Windows?

Comment: I can't get to set anything but an absolute path to a shortcut. What windows version are you using? When I try to use %cd% it just tries c:\ as a path, instead of c:\temp\ which is where my testfile is located.

Comment: Windows doesn't support this feature AND this is a duplicate question of this: 
https://superuser.com/questions/508684/modifying-windows-shortcut-lnk-files-target-into-a-relative-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying Windows Shortcut .lnk-file's target into a relative path](https://superuser.com/questions/508684/modifying-windows-shortcut-lnk-files-target-into-a-relative-path)

Comment: Is the rule the same for icons? The duplicate is about the shortcut itself, not the icon. Is the answer the same for both?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas No it answers nothing. I want to change the ICON's path, not the TARGET's path. They are two different things.

Comment: @music2myear to be clear, as I explain in my question, the TARGET's path be relative to any folder in your system. It's the ICON's path I am having trouble with.

Comment: `SeñorCMasMas No it answers nothing` .. the system automatically generates this question.  I did not write this comment.  It is the result of suggesting that it might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is **not** supported for icon file paths in a `.lnk` shortcut file. Windows does not want to regularly recalculate paths for icons.

The "Correct" way to do this is to create your own `.exe` launcher file with the required icon embedded. There are even `.bat`-to-`.exe` file converter tools that allow for custom icons. You might want to ask in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For totally dynamic environment, I've prepped setup that i think could be used. Once you add a line to your **.bat** file, you will need to run it once, so it create a shortcut on your desktop, after that, you can run it from shortcut. In essence, 1st time it has to be "initialized".

I got four icons to dynamically change icon on shortcut, tho i could use for this example default Windows icons, i will expand on ability for icon changes according to path;

```
1. windows.ico -> https://icon-icons.com/downloadimage.php?id=27087&root=251/ICO/256/&file=Windows-01_27087.ico
2. progra_1.ico -> https://icon-icons.com/downloadimage.php?id=250639&root=3934/ICO/512/&file=default_program_folder_icon_250639.ico 
3. users.ico -> https://icon-icons.com/downloadimage.php?id=14636&root=80/ICO/256/&file=user_accounts_15362.ico
4. default.ico -> https://icon-icons.com/downloadimage.php?id=21215&root=161/ICO/256/&file=default_22735.ico
```

Directory location for this setup is irrelevant, it is where **YourFile.bat** is located.

I will assume your **.bat** will be always on same disk where Windows is installed, if its not,
there should be plenty of examples for "bypass".
In most default cases, Windows is installed on C: drive. Windows will recognize that partition as %systemdrive% in Command shell.

For initial setup i will place main **.bat** file to;

```
%systemdrive%\path\to\mybat
```

and i will name it **MyFile.bat**.
This file represents your **.bat** file and you need only add one line to your .bat;

```
cscript "%~dp0MyIconFix.vbs"
```

The rest of code I will place in VBS file and name it **MyIconFix.vbs**

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
scriptDir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

lnkName = "notetest.lnk"
batName = "MyFile.bat"
locDesktop = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
lnkPath = objFSO.BuildPath(locDesktop, lnkName)
UserOneD = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemdrive%\Users\%username%\OneDrive")
Progra_1 = "C:\Program "
Progra_2 = "C:\Program"
Sys32Folder = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemdrive%\Windows\System32")
WinFolder = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
UserDocs = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemdrive%\Users\%username%\Documents")

If InStr(1, scriptDir, Progra_1) = 1 Then
    iconPath = scriptDir & "icofolder\progra_1.ico"
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, Progra_2) = 1 Then
    iconPath = "%windir%\system32\imageres.dll,70"
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, Sys32Folder) = 1 Then
    iconPath = "%windir%\system32\imageres.dll, 9"
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, WinFolder) = 1 Then
    iconPath = scriptDir & "icofolder\windows.ico"
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, UserDocs) = 1 Then
    iconPath = scriptDir & "icofolder\users.ico"
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, locDesktop) = 1 Then
    iconPath = "%systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll,186"
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, UserOneD) = 1 Then
    iconPath = "%systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll,221"
Else
    iconPath = "icofolder\default.ico"
End If

If (objFSO.FileExists(lnkPath)) Then
    Set objShortcut1 = objShell.CreateShortcut(locDesktop & "\" & lnkName)
    objShortcut1.TargetPath = scriptDir & batName
    objShortcut1.WorkingDirectory = scriptDir
    objShortcut1.IconLocation = iconPath
    objShortcut1.Save
Else
    Set objShortcut1 = objShell.CreateShortcut(locDesktop & "\" & lnkName)
    objShortcut1.TargetPath = scriptDir & batName
    objShortcut1.WindowStyle = 1
    objShortcut1.WorkingDirectory = scriptDir
    objShortcut1.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+Y"
    objShortcut1.Description = "Shortcut to MyBat."
    objShortcut1.IconLocation = iconPath
    objShortcut1.Save
End If
```

You can also add some log in case you want to track you paths, or if you move some of your code into script, log will be generated at same place where your bat is;

```
debugOn = False
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
scriptDir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If debugOn Then
    Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(scriptDir & "MyBat.Log", True)
    objLogFile.WriteLine "Script Directory: " & scriptDir
End If

lnkName = "notetest.lnk"
batName = "MyFile.bat"
locDesktop = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
lnkPath = objFSO.BuildPath(locDesktop, lnkName)
UserOneD = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemdrive%\Users\%username%\OneDrive")
Progra_1 = "C:\Program "
Progra_2 = "C:\Program"
Sys32Folder = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemdrive%\Windows\System32")
WinFolder = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
UserDocs = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemdrive%\Users\%username%\Documents")

If InStr(1, scriptDir, Progra_1) = 1 Then
    iconPath = scriptDir & "icofolder\progra_1.ico"
    If debugOn Then
        objLogFile.WriteLine "FOUND:" & scriptDir & " matches the pattern C:\Program Files\"
    End If
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, Progra_2) = 1 Then
    iconPath = "%windir%\system32\imageres.dll,70"
    If debugOn Then
        objLogFile.WriteLine scriptDir & " matches the pattern C:\ProgramData\"
    End If
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, Sys32Folder) = 1 Then
    iconPath = "%windir%\system32\imageres.dll, 9"
    If debugOn Then
        objLogFile.WriteLine scriptDir & " matches the pattern C:\Windows\System32\"
    End If
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, WinFolder) = 1 Then
    iconPath = scriptDir & "icofolder\windows.ico"
    If debugOn Then
        objLogFile.WriteLine scriptDir & " matches the pattern C:\Windows\"
    End If
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, UserDocs) = 1 Then
    iconPath = scriptDir & "icofolder\users.ico"
    If debugOn Then
        objLogFile.WriteLine scriptDir & " matches the pattern C:\Users\*\Documents"
    End If
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, locDesktop) = 1 Then
    iconPath = "%systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll,186"
    If debugOn Then
        expandUser = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(" matches the pattern C:\Users\%username%\Desktop")
        objLogFile.WriteLine scriptDir & expandUser
    End If
ElseIf InStr(1, scriptDir, UserOneD) = 1 Then
    iconPath = "%systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll,221"
    If debugOn Then
        expandUser = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(" matches the pattern %UserOneD%")
        objLogFile.WriteLine scriptDir & expandUser
    End If
Else
    iconPath = "icofolder\default.ico"
    If debugOn Then
        objLogFile.WriteLine scriptDir & " doesnt match any known folder, default ico applied!"
    End If
End If

If debugOn Then
    objLogFile.WriteLine "Icon Path: " & iconPath
    objLogFile.WriteLine "Desk Path: " & locDesktop
    objLogFile.WriteLine "lnk Name: " & lnkName
    objLogFile.WriteLine "lnk Path: " & lnkPath
    objLogFile.WriteLine "lnkScriptDir: " & scriptDir & lnkName
End If


If (objFSO.FileExists(lnkPath)) Then
    Set objShortcut1 = objShell.CreateShortcut(locDesktop & "\" & lnkName)
    objShortcut1.TargetPath = scriptDir & batName
    objShortcut1.WorkingDirectory = scriptDir
    objShortcut1.IconLocation = iconPath
    objShortcut1.Save
    If debugOn Then
        objLogFile.WriteLine lnkPath & " exists on the desktop."
    End If
Else
    Set objShortcut1 = objShell.CreateShortcut(locDesktop & "\" & lnkName)
    objShortcut1.TargetPath = scriptDir & batName
    objShortcut1.WindowStyle = 1
    objShortcut1.WorkingDirectory = scriptDir
    objShortcut1.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+Y"
    objShortcut1.Description = "Shortcut to MyBat."
    objShortcut1.IconLocation = iconPath
    objShortcut1.Save
    If debugOn Then
        objLogFile.WriteLine scriptDir & lnkName & " is created at:" & locDesktop
    End If
End If
objLogFile.Close
```

Now you can move that whole folder anywhere on your main drive.

Comment: That is not relative to the folder where the `bat` file is. It is relative to windir. I cannot use that =(

Comment: So %SystemDrive%\path\to\folder\file.bat(ico) doesn't work for you?
Image is just an example of sys variable use(both are available in Pe also).

%CD% is(if im not wrong) CMD.exe built-in variable.

You can set icon only if .bat/ico has static folder across all devices, than .lnk can be anywhere you want on any of devices.

[![movablelnk.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/0yfyhmFc/movablelnk.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/211YZqzZ)

Comment: The problem here is that I don't know where the icon file will be. All I know is it will be in a path relative to the current directory.

Comment: Use your bat file to set the icon in that case, since everything is dynamic?
Add ModMyIcon.vbs to execute from same location where bat is;

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
location = objShell.CurrentDirectory
scriptDir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))

iconPath = scriptDir & "icofolder\Wizard.ico"

Set objShortcut1 = objShell.CreateShortcut(location & "\notetest.lnk")
objShortcut1.IconLocation = iconPath
objShortcut1.Save

Change;"icofolder\Wizard.ico" and "\notetest.lnk" to suit your needs.

Comment: Can you turn this into an answer? I don't quite fully grasp what is happening here. 
Is your bat file changing the icon of the shortcut on the fly?

Comment: No,bat is calling vba script. You must make that part of code a "name.vbs" script and save it in same place where your .bat is.
Try in your bat with something like;
cscript "%~dp0testicochange.vbs"

Comment: Updated the script, see if you can find something additional or new for your needs.